# How to disable macOS dark mode for pyside2 / pyqt scripts?

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyside2

I've got several scripts with small GUIs written with PySide2. A lot of them have parts with individual widget stylesheets and are not readable in macOS dark mode.

So instead of updating the GUIs I'd like to disable dark mode completely for certain scripts.

I know about the `Info.plist` setting, but this is not applicable for single python scripts, only for frozen and bundled applications. Also I found no way to use the light palette by default. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could define your own stylesheet in your QMainWindow Stylesheet:

```
stylesheet = """
    * {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    }
    QLabel {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    }
    QPushButton {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    }

  etc.

"""
window.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

and if you want this to happen only on macOS:

```
from sys import platform as _platform
if(_platform=='darwin'):
    window.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

Comment: Then what if the OS is *not* in dark mode while starting and/or the mode changes while the program is running?

Comment: @musicamante The stylesheet of the app will be always the same (black text over white in this case). It does not affect changing the theme, because the stylesheet overwrites it.